# whether to use 'was' or 'were' in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Should i Use 'was' or 'were' in this below sentence?

About three tonnes of the chemical was exported to Israel at Rs17,431 per kg

About three tonne of the chemical was exported to Israel at Rs17,431 per kg  (tonne)

Answer (score 1):

The subject in the sentence is *three tonnes*. The *of* phrase that follows is irrelevant to the syntax:

> **One tonne** *[of X]* **was** shipped.
>         One tonne of ripe bananas was shipped.
>         One tonne of paper was shipped.
>
> **Three tonnes** *[of X*] **were** shipped.
>         Three tonnes of ripe bananas were shipped.
>         Three tonnes of paper were shipped.

So, the grammatical version of your sentence is:

> ✔ About three tonnes of the chemical were shipped to Israel at Rs17,431 per kg.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Good Days to You.